# node with postgres createdb raise error of role does not exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am building a api in node using postgresql. I am using sequelize as ORM. and when I am running following command to create database:

```
createdb bookstore
```

I am getting following error:

```
createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "ubox18" does not exist
```

Below is my configuration file:

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "bookstore",
    "port": 5432,
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "test": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
  "production": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "postgres",
    "database": "database_production",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help what I am missing here?

Comment: read trough this http://learn.linksprite.com/pcduino/linux-applications/postgresql-createdb-could-not-connect-to-database-postgres-fatal-peer-authentication-failed-for-user-postgres/      or this https://techglimpse.com/createuser-could-not-connect-to-database-postgres/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
createdb -U postgres bookstore
```

The 'createdb' utility pick the database user from the OS user, unless you choose another database user with the option -U